# Copy formula to range. Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have this script :

```
function addConsultant()
{
var sheet_staffing = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Staffing"); 
var sheet_parametres = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Parametres");
var range_tabConsultant_default = sheet_parametres.getRange(26,1,6,64);
var row_position_newTab = sheet_parametres.getRange(1,1).getValue();
range_tabConsultant_default.copyFormatToRange(sheet_staffing, 1, 36, row_position_newTab, row_position_newTab + 6);
range_tabConsultant_default.copyValuesToRange(sheet_staffing, 1, 36, row_position_newTab, row_position_newTab + 6);
sheet_parametres.getRange(1,1).setValue(row_position_newTab+6);
}
```

This is like a default tab, their is one tab per person, but I dont know how to copy formulas from def tab to tab created by script. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range.html#getFormulas) and [getFormulasR1C1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range.html#getFormulasR1C1) methods of the `Range` class.
You'll also need to use the corresponding `setFormulas` or `setFormulasR1C1`.

[edit: to answer the comments]

If in the multi-cell range you're copying mixed values and formulas. You'll have to break up the calls into multiple sets, for either value or formula, as a single cell can only have one (or parse the plain values into simple formulas, e.g. ="value").

To have your formulas "following" the reference, use the `set/getFormulasR1C1` notation instead of the simpler `set/getFormulas`.

Comment: Its working, but not as I expected, for exemple, I want D40 =sum(D41:D45) but the next tab I'll add on my sheet will need the formula D46=(D47:D51). No way to do that?

Comment: And if I set this : range_newTab.setFormulas(Formulas_tab); before my CopyValueToRange(), it dont work, and if I set it after, CopyValueToRange() dont work.

Comment: Ok, after all its working, but if I use a copyValueToRange, I've to use many setFormula (because setFormulas dont work). Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

What if the script used the Current sheet the user was looking at with this function ? [GetActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getActiveSheet)

Comment: I dont think it will work, because if the user launch the script from the wrong sheet, it will make a tab on the sheet and overwrite information. Its why Im using a cell with the position of the row that is after the last tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample how to copy formula in `A1` to `A2:A` range with relative references:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet.getRange("A2:A").setFormulaR1C1(sheet.getRange("A1").getFormulaR1C1());
```